# JavaFX Text control: Setting the Fill Color

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a working `TextField` with my CSS fill color, and a `Label`.  But when I try a `Text` control, I have not figured out how to set the fill color in CSS (and I have tried many things).

```
Label label = new Label("Machine ID");
TextField textField = new TextField("1");
Text text = new Text("1");
```

.css:

```
.text-input {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;    
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First note that [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) has no style class by default. So you need to add the style class:

```
Text text = new Text("1");
text.getStyleClass().add("my-text");
```

Then you can use the `-fx-fill` property inherited from [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape):

```css
.my-text {
    -fx-fill: blue ;
}
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextCSSTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(10);

        TextField textField = new TextField("Text Field");

        Label label = new Label("Label");

        Text text = new Text("Text");
        text.getStyleClass().add("my-text");

        root.getChildren().addAll(textField, label, text);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("text-css-test.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

text-css-test.css:

```css
.my-text {
    -fx-fill: blue ;
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: green ;
} 

.text-input {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  So I see `Text` is a `Shape`, and not a `Control`!  It does seem like quite a peculiar class of object.

Comment: Yes: I've never found much use for `Text` and tend to prefer `Label`. But then I tend to write more business-type apps and generally use `Control` classes. If you use a control, (i.e. instantiate a `Control` or any subclass), it forces loading of the default CSS stylesheet and effectively enables the CSS engine. If you have an application which uses only `Shape`s, CSS isn't enabled unless you force it. This might be applicable in a game, for example, where you manage your own graphics and layout and want to avoid the performance overhead of CSS. `Text` could be used in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text), [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) doesn't have this property like [Label](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label) and [TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textfield) do. So I'm not sure it is possible.