# JavaFX Can't set any styles with Text node

Tags: javafx

I have a text field and I'm able to change the text size of a `Text` node no problem with

```
Text text = new Text();
text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16;");
```

but if I try to change the colour, nothing works:

```
textStart.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16;-fx-color: #ff0000;-fx-text-base-color: #ff0000;-fx-text-fill: #ff0000;");
```

I find in JavaFX every node seems to need a different css command to successfully change the colour, but with `Text`, none of them seem to work. I can change the text with

```
text.setFill(Color.RED);
```

But it's awkward to have two separate commands on separate lines when it should be able to be done in one line of css. Especially since what I'm doing is relatively heavy processing of many lines of text.

Does anyone know what the css command to change the colour is with a `Text` node? Seems so odd it only accepts the size command in css..

Comment: `text.setStyle("-fx-fill:your-color")`

Comment: @Alex My god that really works, thanks. Why in the world do they use a different css tag for every different node to set the text colour? Like for example for `Label` it's set with `-fx-text-fill` and with `Button` it's set with `-fx-text-base-color`....so weird.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX Text control: Setting the Fill Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689441/javafx-text-control-setting-the-fill-color)

Comment: @kleopatra If the title wasn't so dumb I would've found that before. 'Fill colour" sounds more like a background colour although for that it wouldn't be that clear either. It doesn't help that Javafx has different css to do the exact same thing with each node...unlike ..cough....css.